# Visibility changes "by itself"

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have this `ListView` with an `Adapter` that extends `BaseAdapter`. Inside the

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {...}
```

I attach a `clickListener` to `view` like this:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final LinearLayout llMatchInfo = v.findViewById(R.id.matchInfo);
        if (llMatchInfo == null) return;
        llMatchInfo.setVisibility(llMatchInfo.getVisibility() == View.GONE ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Then I have this one user complaining that when he clicks an element `llMatchInfo` is visible for a split second and then disappears again.

This is the only place the `matchInfo` view has it's visibility changed.

Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Here's the outer XML for each item in my ListView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/live_indicator">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/match_data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            ...

        </LinearLayout>

        <include
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/match_info"
            android:id="@+id/matchInfo" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the inner XML for the actual matchInfo (the part I want to toggle visibility on):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/team_logos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
        ... />

        <ImageView
        ... />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        ... />

    <TextView
        ... />

    <TextView
        ... />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tv_channels"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
        ... />

        <ImageView
        ... />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to put the findViewBuyId() outside the onclick(). And please add the XML

Comment: Added XML to OP